# SELECT 1 FROM and if statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement, mysqli

Im doing some sort of badge system for a site Im currently developing and have got stuck when checking my MySQL database.

I want to check if the user already have got the badge, if not, put it in.

Here is my code:

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$badgename = "222asd";



$results=mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM badges WHERE badge = '$badgename' AND mid = '$userid'");
if ($results>0)

{
    echo 'You already have this badge'; 
}
else
{
    echo 'You deserved a new badge';
}
```

The problem is that I always get the message "You already have this badge" even though I change the $badgename variable to something that is not in the database.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Edit: 
Im trying to use MySQLI now instead since you recommended so. I have some questions for you regarding this.

```
$numberofposts=$row['posts'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$badgename = "222asd551222";


if($numberofposts >= 10){


$results=mysqli_query("SELECT 1 FROM `badges` WHERE `mid`='$userid' AND 'badge' =     '$badgename'");

if($results->num_rows <= 0) {
        mysqli_query("INSERT INTO badges ('mid', 'badge') VALUES ('$userid',     '$badgename')");
}


}
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, there's a few things going on.  First, let's solve your problem:

```
$results=mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM badges WHERE badge = '$badgename' AND mid = '$userid'");
if ($results>0) {
```

Since $results is *a resource*, it will *always* return > 0.  So change it like so:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
```

Second, why not `SELECT badge FROM badges`, instead of a (strange-looking) `SELECT 1`...

And, **do not use** mysql.  It is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).  Choose a different [database API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! Will definitely look into mysqli and PDO. What is the big differences between them and MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call mysql_num_rows e.g. like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect(/* user, ... */);

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$badgename = "222asd";



$results=mysql_query("SELECT 1 FROM badges WHERE badge = '$badgename' AND mid = '$userid' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)

{
    echo 'You already have this badge';
}
else
{
    echo 'You deserved a new badge';
}
```

And as cale_b pointed out and the manual states: the mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the not to distant future.

I would recommend something like this (with the added benefit, that any `'` or watherver inside your parameter is properly escaped:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$badgename = "222asd";

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM badges WHERE badge = :badgename AND mid = :userid LIMIT 1");
$query->execute(array(':badgename' => $badgename, ':userid' => $userid)) or die("Could not execute statement");
if ($query->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo 'You already have this badge';
} else {
    echo 'You deserved a new badge';
}
```

Also note I added `LIMIT 1`to your statement as it seems you are not interested in finding out how many badges of this type the user has; this way your query will run a bit faster as the DB does not need to look for any further matches after the first one.
[More information on using PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which now also comes bundled wih PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use count, which I would prefer in those cases over `mysql_num_rows`

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM badges WHERE badge = '$badgename' AND mid = '$userid'"));
if ($row[0]) ...
```

btw. you should not insert a variable like that into a query. At best use the new mysqli extension and use a prepared statement. If this is not an option for you, you should at least call `mysql_real_escape_string` onto the variable before inserting it into the sql statement.